# Proper way to represent a NULL key value in a raw sockets based query on HandlerSocket

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, nosql, handlersocket

I wrote a lightweight sockets based HandlerSocket query system and it's worked perfectly.... short of this one little problem....

I have a table in the DB that has a `unique` index with 5 key parts:

```
function, type, parameter, Module_ID, Site_ID
```

All are strings, the first 4 columns are required, the last (Site_ID) is not AND it may be `NULL`. The brief explanation is that all Sites share records that have a `Site_ID = NULL`, however each Site can override the default record with one of it's own with their specific `Site_ID` supplied.

My Sockets query prepares the request like so:

```
$request = array(
            'indexid' => $key,
            'op' => $query->get_type(),
            'vlen' => count($query->get_keys()),
            'keys' => implode("\t",$query->get_key_values()),
            'limit' => $query->get_limit(),
            'offset' => $query->get_offset());

// Join as TAB separated values
$request = implode("\t",$request)."\n";
```

So when all 5 column parts and key values are supplied it works, when the first 4 columns and first 4 key values are supplied it works, but when all 5 columns and their corresponding key values with the 5th being `NULL` are used, it returns nothing when I know for a fact there are records that match the first 4 and have a `NULL` Site_ID.

I MUST be able to use the 3rd scenario because I need to be sure that it doesn't match any that have Site_ID's defined.

I'm assuming that the issues lies in the `\t` joined key values but I'm not sure what the correct value to use here is to match a NULL column value... because it's not `NULL`.

If anyone can shed some light on the correct way of formatting this request so that it can match the `NULL` 5th column, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, it helps to Re-RTM... which can be found here: https://github.com/ahiguti/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL/blob/master/docs-en/protocol.en.txt

In the opening section `Basic syntax`, it states that:

```
NULL is expressed as a single NUL(0x00).
```

And so I've adjusted my key value preparation to the following:

```
$values = $query->get_key_values();
foreach ($values as $vid => $value) { if (!isset($value)) { $values[$vid] = "\x00"; } }
$values = implode("\t",$values); // TAB Separated
```

This replaces all native `NULL` values with a HEX Null byte which is differentiated from an empty string allowing the server to match the column to `NULL` values.

Hope that helps someone else.